# How to save frames every nth second, in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to save a frame every 0.05 sec but my solution doesn't seem to work. What changes should I make to my code?

> fps = 18 rate = 1/18 or 0.05

```
source = "video.mp4"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('source/%s' % source)
frame_count = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))


count = 0
rate = round((1/fps), 3) - 0.006 # rounds to 0.05 sec
# 1 frame = 0.05 sec -> 18 frames = 0.9 or 1 sec
sec = 0
# 0.5
# 0.1
# 0.15
# ...

while True:
    sec = sec + rate
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, sec*1000) # sec*1000 converts to ms
    ret, frame = cap.read() 
    if not ret:
        cap.release()
        break
    else:
        cv2.imwrite("../frames/" + "frame%d.jpg" % count, frame)
    count += 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use this:

```
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, sec*1000)
```

inside your loop, you are effectively trying to *seek* (i.e. set your position) backwards and forwards inside your video in order to read each frame. I think you'll do much better reading all the frames in a linear fashion and discarding the ones you don't want, so if the frame rate is 60fps and you want 15fps, just save every 4th frame:

```
if frameCounter % 4 == 0:
    cv2.imwrite(...)
```

Comment: The file is already at 18fps but I want to read frames at 0.05 sec intervals if you know what I mean. For example, F1 saved at 0 sec, F2 saved at 0.05 sec, F3 saved at 0.1 sec, F4 saved at 0.15sec etc.

Comment: You only have 18 distinct images each second, i.e. one at the start, one at 55ms, one at 110ms so you can't possibly know for sure what was visible at 50ms and 100ms. If you just want to change the rate, you can do it readily with `ffmpeg` like this https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/ChangingFrameRate